# NameError: name 'ProfileView' is not defined

Tags: python, django

when trying to run server im getting this
path("accounts", ProfileView.as_view(template_name="profile.html")),
NameError: name 'ProfileView' is not defined

#APPS/ACCOUNTS/URLS

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from . import views

app_name="accounts"
urlpatterns = [
    path("accounts", ProfileView.as_view(template_name="profile.html")),
    #Django-AUTH
    path(
        "login", 
        auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="accounts/login.html"), 
        name="login"
    ),
    path("logout", auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
]
```

#websiteproject/views.py

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "profile.html"
```

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` in `apps/accounts`?

Comment: Yes i do, have an __init__.py on apps/accounts

Comment: OK, can you post your `apps/accounts/views.py` as well then please? I'm somewhat confused why the error shoes a blank module name !!

Comment: you are doing things the wrong way, you are using Function based views FBV approach,   refer to this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/ on how to use CBV (class based views)

Comment: @cizario thank you! yes i believe thats the doc i need.

Answer (score 0):

`views.ProfileView.as_view()` Looks like a class based views implementation.
Further, I don't see `ProfileView` class In `views.py`

For reference, look at the class [SendMessage](https://github.com/addu390/django-kafka/blob/master/publish_subscribe/views.py) and as view in [URL](https://github.com/addu390/django-kafka/blob/master/publish_subscribe/urls.py)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i updated the code and error.

Comment: Are you getting the same error?, your import statement seems to be wrong, it should be `from .views import ProfileView`.

Comment: Im getting this error now -->   from . import ProfileView
ImportError: cannot import name 'ProfileView' from 'weedmanweeds.apps.accounts' (C:\Users\Ivan\Documents\webdjango\weedmanweeds\apps\accounts\__init__.py)

Comment: Did you use relative imports? as shown above `from .views import ProfileView`

Comment: As per your prior comment, `C:\Users\Ivan\Documents\webdjango\weedmanweeds\apps\accounts_init_.py`.
It should be `C:\Users\Ivan\Documents\webdjango\weedmanweeds\apps\accounts\_init_.py`
`__init__.py` is the file name.

Comment: this is what im getting: line 8, in <module>
    path("accounts", ProfileView.as_view(template_name="profile.html")),
NameError: name 'ProfileView' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Code corrected, server running correctly and website/accounts/profile displaying profile.html

```
{% block content %}
<h1>
    {{user.username}} Profile
</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

#URLS

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from weedmanweeds.views import ProfileView

app_name="accounts"
urlpatterns = [
    path("profile", 

ProfileView.as_view(template_name="accounts/profile.html"),name="profile"),
        #Django-AUTH
        path(
            "login", 
            auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="accounts/login.html"), 
            name="login"
        ),
        path("logout", auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    ]
```

#VIEWS.PY

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "accounts/profile.html"
```